# Flutter Android/IOS - Dynamic list with TextInputAction.next not behaving as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dynamic list containing TextFormFields. I've added a `textInputAction` with `TextInputAction.next` as the value, so it will move to the next field upon clicking next. At the bottom of the page, I've added a button to click finish. The app `Scaffold` has the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to `true`, so the TextFields scroll upon reaching the bottom.

The button needs to be outside of the ScrollableView so it's always visible at the bottom.
The issue is that when I click next, the keyboard closes when reaching the button, which is not intended behavior.

Also when I add a Padding of 15 the issue is resolved on my phone but not others, so that is not a valid solution.

I've created a sample project where on my phone (Samsung S22) it doesn't work:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const ItemList(),
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ItemList({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ItemList> createState() => _ItemListState();
}

class _ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    items.addAll(List<String>.generate(20, (int index) => 'String$index',
        growable: true));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('Title: '),
                    Text('Value'),
                  ],
                ),
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final item = items[index];
                      final bool isLast = items.length - 1 == index;
                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(item),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 20,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              onTapOutside: (_) =>
                                  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
                              textInputAction: isLast
                                  ? TextInputAction.done
                                  : TextInputAction.next,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                isDense: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const SizedBox(
                height: 40,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Finish'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

1. I've tried adding a Stack and placing the button behind the List.
2. I've placed `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` on `false` but the page didn't scroll to my TextFormField anymore.
3. I've added a padding but that only works for my screen size.

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72818#issuecomment-752892993). I only needed to add the following to the button:

```
ElevatedButton(
  focusNode:  FocusNode(skipTraversal: true), //new line
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const SizedBox(
    height: 40,
    child: Center(
      child: Text('Finish'),
    ),
  ),
```